# JQuery targeting child

Tags: jquery, html, children

I want to target the second `<tr>` and the second `<td>` tag using JQuery. I know I could give the `<td>` tag a class and just target that one but I want to do it this way. This is what I've got so far:

```
$('#playlist tr:nth-child(2)');
```

```html
<table id="playlist">
    <tr class="bold">
        <td>ID:</td>
        <td>Track-Name:</td>
        <td>Artist:</td>
        <td>Duration:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="idD">1</td>
        <td id="first" song="Weown.mp3" cover="cover.jpg" artist="The Wanted">We Own The Night</td>
        <td>The Wanted</td>
        <td class="idD">3:25</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Given that that element has an `id` on it, just `#first` should work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be:

```
$('#playlist tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kzwbkfz3/

Answer (score 1):

Consider following:

```
$('#playlist tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)')
//or
$('#playlist tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)')
```

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/fx5ogbk7/)

> Details: [**:nth-child()**](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), [**:eq()**](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are correct but you can also use [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$("#playlist tr").eq(2).find('td').eq(2);
```

check the [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/touqeershafi/aL5eL7sy/)